# Parser Error in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net

### Server Error in '/elogs' Application.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'IND:InderGrid'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/eLogS_Sea/New_MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="eLogS_Sea_Default2" Title="Untitled Page" %>
Line 2:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
Line 3:      <IND:InderGrid ID="inderGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="4" CheckBoxColumn="true"      
Line 4:          CustomPageing="true" Font-Names="Tahoma" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
Line 5:          OnPageIndexChanging="inderGrid_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCreated="inderGrid_RowCreated"


Source File: /elogs/eLogS_Sea/Default2.aspx    Line: 3
```

Any one please Help Immediatly

Answer (score 1):

You might need to register the control on the page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="header" Src="Controls/Header.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="footer" Src="Controls/Footer.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ControlVendor" Assembly="ControlVendor" %>

<html>
  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <scott:header ID="MyHeader" runat="server" />
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This was taken from [Scott Gu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx)

Comment: Where does the InderGrid come from?  is it another control (as in InderGrid.ascx) or is it from a dll?

Comment: Then at the top of Default2.aspx under <%@ Page Language="C#" add:
<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="footer" Src="<path>/ InderGrid.ascx" %>

Comment: sorry, it comes from dll name is Indrajeet.dll

Comment: Add the following and replace namespace (make sure it is included in the project references): <%@ Register TagPrefix="IND" Namespace="Indrajeet" Assembly="Indrajeet" %>